# How to execute a large script on each database in an instance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I execute a large (>40k char) block of T-SQL on each database in a MSSQL instance, considering the following have character limits which would truncate the command passed in a variable, and I have to reference the database name in the block of code:

- sp_foreachdb
- sp_executesql
- EXEC

Comment: An `nvarchar(max)` variable will not get truncated unless you do something to it that causes truncation. [This stored procedure](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) should handle 40K strings just fine, but you can't expect to print 40K worth of output to preview/validate. See [this tip for a potential workaround](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/).

Comment: You can always convert a large query into dynamic, too. Text editors like notepad++ are helpful, can highlight similar, and are very quick in comparison. The other suggestion is split the code into section, and control+H your way into converting the working sql into dynamic. Personally, I would suggest splitting it in a way that compartmentalizes what you are doing. Imagine if you have to re-edit this stuff later. :/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. nvarchar(max) isn't the problem, and splitting doesn't help. The sp's / command I listed are truncating the query. It occurred to me to create a stored procedure with the query and pass the necessary variable to it when executing it. I'm going to try that next. Thanks.